# backbone collection fetch error

Tags: json, backbone.js

I'm trying to fetch a collection from a .json file. Here is my collection code

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'vent'], function($, _, Backbone, vent) {
'use strict';

    var Wine = Backbone.Model.extend({
        urlRoot: "js/models/wines.json",
        defaults: {
            "id": null,
            "name":  "",
            "grapes":  "",
            "country":  "USA",
            "region":  "California",
            "year":  "",
            "description":  "",
            "picture":  ""
        }
    });

    return Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Wine,
        url: "js/models/wines.json",
    });
});
```

I'm fetching the collection like this:

```
var _wine = new wineCollection();
_wine.fetch({
    success : function(data) {
        console.log("ON SUCCESS");
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(response) {
        console.log("ON ERROR");
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

In the console it's always showing the "ON ERROR" message:

```
ON ERROR
child
  _byCid: Object
  _byId: Object
  _callbacks: Object
  length: 0
  models: Array[0]
  __proto__: ctor
```

And here is one item of my wines.json file

```
{"id":"9","name":"BLOCK NINE","year":"2009","grapes":"Pinot Noir","country":"USA","region":"California","description":"With hints of ginger and spice, this wine makes an excellent complement to light appetizer and dessert fare for a holiday gathering.","picture":"block_nine.jpg"}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You only need to specify either `url` in `collection` or `urlRoot` in `model`. Well specifying both won't create any problem. And Not sure how your `json` file is, in your file, just wrap all `json` objects in an array and give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried inspecting the collection class in the fetch method (what is actually send over).
You might need to override the parse method in order to access an inner part of the data send over.

For instance:

```
Wine.Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

//we need to parse only the inner list
parse : function (response) {
    this.cursor = response.cursor;
    return response.list;
}
```

Where the array is an inner list: **{list: [{item: one}, {item: two}]}**